# Why is a custom field I programmatically created shown as disabled?

Tags: 8, entities

I created a Drupal 8 module for creating a custom field. I wrote the code basing on the documentation given in [Create a custom field widget](https://www.drupal.org/node/2620968), [Create a custom field formatter](https://www.drupal.org/node/2620966), and [Create a custom field type](https://www.drupal.org/node/2052601).

I created the *.info.yml* file, three directories src/Plugin/Field (*FieldFormatter*, *FieldType*, and *FieldWidget*) where I put the files described in those documentation guides.
I could see the custom field in the field list, but it is shown as disabled.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Add a screenshot, it might also be useful to share your code. I'm not sure what you mean exactly.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I've created a custom field type and when I create a field in the UI I can't place it anywhere under "Manage form display". The field is always in the 'disabled' section. The widget selection drop down says 'hidden' and doesn't have any other options.

Comment: There are so many tiny things that can make a custom field not work. I don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

After the field is created and the field instance is added, you need to enable the field in the display settings for the form, for example with the following code.

```php
entity_get_form_display('node', $bundle, 'default')
  ->setComponent('field_custom', array(
    'type' => 'string'
  ))
  ->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the issue in my case was that I was using `default_widget = "options_select"` in my FieldType plugin but the options_select widget does not allow my custom field type.

The solution was to create a custom FieldWidget plugin which extends the OptionsSelectWidget and in the field_types declare my custom field type.

This allowed my field to be placed in the form correctly and the options widget to be used.